# Combine variable value and string to use in another variable name

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to combine a variable value and a string value into one. The problem is in the function. Iam trying to pull the name of a resource in the "resources" variable and this needs to be combine with "Amount" at the end in a new variable called "resourceName". For example "FoodAmount" but it ends up giving undefined back when I try to use this in my function.

Any help would be appreciated

```
var resources = [
  "Food",
  "Wood",
  "Stone",
  "Coal",
  "Copper",
  "Silver",
  "Gold",
  "Diamonds"
];

var playerData = [
  {"foodName":"Food", "FoodAmount":"100"},
  {"woodName":"Wood", "WoodAmount":"0"},
  {"stoneName":"Stone", "StoneAmount":"0"},
  {"coalName":"Coal", "CoalAmount":"0"},
  {"copperName":"Copper", "CopperAmount":"0"},
  {"silverName":"Silver", "SilverAmount":"0"},
  {"goldName":"Gold", "GoldAmount":"0"},
  {"diamondsName":"Diamonds", "DiamondsAmount":"0"},
]

function updateResources() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= playerData.length - 1; i++) {
        resourceName = resources[i] + "Amount";
        console.log(playerData[i].resourceName); // Returns undefined??
        document.getElementById(resources[i]).innerHTML = playerData[i].resourceName; // Will also return undefined but should be equel to FoodAmount for the first one and so on
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `playerData[i][resourceName]` (note the square brackets `[...]` instead of the dot `.`). `object.property` is just shorthand for `object["property"]` and doesn't index the object by the variable `property` but rather by the string `"property"` which yields `undefined` as all your objects don't have a `"resourceName"` property set.

Comment: Thank you this worked just the way I wanted it to!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var resources = [
  "Food",
  "Wood",
  "Stone",
  "Coal",
  "Copper",
  "Silver",
  "Gold",
  "Diamonds"
];

var playerData = [
  {"foodName":"Food", "FoodAmount":"100"},
  {"woodName":"Wood", "WoodAmount":"0"},
  {"stoneName":"Stone", "StoneAmount":"0"},
  {"coalName":"Coal", "CoalAmount":"0"},
  {"copperName":"Copper", "CopperAmount":"0"},
  {"silverName":"Silver", "SilverAmount":"0"},
  {"goldName":"Gold", "GoldAmount":"0"},
  {"diamondsName":"Diamonds", "DiamondsAmount":"0"},
]

function updateResources() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= playerData.length - 1; i++) {
        resourceName = resources[i] + "Amount";
        console.log(playerData[i][resourceName]); 
    }
}
```

Because you have a string you need to call the key as an array.

Comment: Thank you for your answear too, this helped visualize what I needed